# fe_sendauth: no password supplied encountered with Amazon RDS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I know many others have encountered this problem, but I'm limited in the Postgres configuration I can do since I am using Amazon RDS...

Here is the relevant section of my **database.yml**

```
default: &default
  host: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_HOST"] %>
  username: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_USER"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"] %>
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  database: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_DB"] %>
  port: 5432
  pool: 5
```

When I hard code the host, leave everything else as is, and load localhost:3000, I get `fe_sendauth: no password supplied` error.  However, when I hard code all of the values instead of using an ENV variable, everything loads as normal with no errors.

I'm using Amazon RDS, so I have no ability to edit pg_hba.conf, but is this just a simpler problem of RoR not having access to ENV variables?

Comment: Unix environment variables are typically set in a file that is read when starting an interactive shell (the ~/.bashrc file for the bash shell, .zshrc for the zsh shell).

To check if you environment variables are set do `echo $POSTGRES_USER` and see if it return a values same for the other environment variables.

Otherwise do inside the termianal `export POSTFRES_USER="YOUR_POSTGRES_USERNAME"`
You’ll have to open a new shell or restart your terminal application to continue. 
you can also put the above commands inside /etc/environment file to load variables on every system restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, it's pretty clear that your ENV values are returning nil. Keep in mind that environment variables are loaded a bit differently on your production server than localhost. In most deployment configurations you can't simply set a Unix environment variable and have it be detectable in `ENV`.

I can't really tell much about how your `ENV` variables are being set from your provided code, but you should consider using Figaro (https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) or dotenv (https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) to manage your ENV variables for you. However, it will require the extra step of having to manage an environment variable file outside of source control.